# dereferencing postgres 2d array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

So I noticed that postgres (9.0) doesn't like it when you dereference a 2d array with only 1 dimension. Here's a funny example

```
WITH my_table(arr) AS ( VALUES (ARRAY[[10,11],[20,21]]) )
SELECT arr[2][1] AS good, arr[1] AS bad FROM my_table;

 good | bad
------+-----
   20 |
(1 row)
```

As you can see this returns `null` when you don't specify the second dimension. Ideally I'd like it to return the inner array `{10,11}`. So to solve this I wrote this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deref_2d(orig_arr numeric[][], inner_arr int)
RETURNS numeric[] AS $$
DECLARE
  index int;
  len int;
  return_arr numeric[];
BEGIN
  len := array_upper(orig_arr,2);
  FOR index IN 1 .. len LOOP
    return_arr[index] := orig_arr[inner_arr][index];
  END LOOP;
  RETURN return_arr;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And now I can write:

```
WITH my_table(arr) AS ( VALUES (ARRAY[[10,11],[20,21]]) )
SELECT deref_2d(arr,1) FROM my_table;
 deref_2d
----------
 {10,11}
```

But multiple things about this make me feel uneasy about my solution. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the full cast of this Western before you write it off:

```
WITH tbl(arr) AS (SELECT (ARRAY[[10,11],[20,21]]))
SELECT arr[2][1]    AS the_good
      ,arr[1]       AS the_bad
      ,arr[1:1]     AS the_ugly   -- first slice of 2D-array
      ,arr[1][1:2]  AS the_ugly_twin -- 2D-array with elements 1 & 2 of 1st slice
      ,ARRAY((SELECT unnest(arr[1:1]))) AS the_righteous -- 1D-array of 1st slice
FROM   tbl;
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1beb2/5) with more examples.

Some background in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS).

Comment: Array slicing FTW! Thanks for showing me this syntax. Where is this documented? I've only been able to find small examples (like this) of most of the postgres nuances.

Comment: @wesdotcool: I have learned a few tricks in the last 12 years I have been working with Postgres. Added links to the manual.