# How to select 1d array from 2d array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array and want to select only the 1st 1d array from it.
How do I do that?

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8137112/398670 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/14743097/398670

Comment: You can get a *slice* of the 2D array, but it's still 2D, just one dimension is flat. E.g. `SELECT (ARRAY [ ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4] ])[1:1];`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the first *slice* of an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT my_arr[1:1];
```

The resulting array has the **same array dimensions** as the input.
Details in my previous answer here:

- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/8142998#8142998)

To **flatten** the result:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT unnest(my_arr[1:1]));
```

Or cleaner:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT * FROM unnest(my_arr)[1:1]));
```

#### Examples

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1:1];
```

Result:

```
{{1,2,3}}  -- 2D array
```

Or:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT unnest((ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1:1])
   );
```

Result:

```
{1,2,3}  -- 1D array
```

#### Emulate `unnest()` in Postgres 8.3

The [Wiki page you are linking to](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest) was a bit misleading. I updated it with code for 2-dimensional arrays.

`unnest()` for 1-dimensional array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_1d(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT $1[i]
FROM   generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i
$func$;
```

`unnest()` for 2-dimensional array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT $1[d1][d2]
FROM   generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) d1
    ,  generate_series(array_lower($1,2), array_upper($1,2)) d2
$func$;
```

The aggregate function `array_agg()` is not installed by default in Postgres 8.3:

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg(anyelement) (
 SFUNC = array_append,
 STYPE = anyarray,
 INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Unnest 2d array to 1d arrays:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d_1d(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg($1[d1][d2])
FROM   generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) d1
    ,  generate_series(array_lower($1,2), array_upper($1,2)) d2
GROUP  BY d1
ORDER  BY d1
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gIQqJz5T)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/78017/1)</sub>

Comment: I wanted 1d array because version of postgres I work on is pretty old (8.3) and there aren't unnest function. So I created function by this link https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest but it is not working for 2d array. With 1d array it works fine.

Comment: @thecoparyew: That information should be in your question to begin with. I updated the misleading Wiki page and added some more to the answer. The other option is to upgrade to a current version of Postgres. [Version 8.3 has reached EOL in Feb. 2013.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: To be didactic, more one information to reader: how to select de second or Nth item (line of the matrix)?  Answer: by slices `x[n:n]`...  but with the same ugly problem, that the slice od 2D is not 1D, is also 2D.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 1st 1D array from a 2D array with these ways below.

```sql
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1:1]; -- {{a,b,c}}
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1:1][:]; -- {{a,b,c}}
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1:1][1:3]; -- {{a,b,c}}
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1][:]; -- {{a,b,c}} -- This is tricky
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1][1:3]; -- {{a,b,c}} -- This is tricky
SELECT (ARRAY[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']])[1]; -- NULL
```