# Postgres - Query Specific Value in an Array of Arrays

Tags: postgresql

I have column that is returning from my query that is an array of array. It looks like this.

array_vals: `{{NULL,NULL,147.89,87.27,82.65,83.41,93.69,101.90,NULL,NULL}}`

When I try to query in to my array first array I always get `Null` values.

`select array_vals[0] from table`

This returns `null`.  But my desired results would be `{NULL,NULL,147.89,87.27,82.65,83.41,93.69,101.90,NULL,NULL}`

```
with test as (
select 1 as value, array_agg(array[1 , 3, 4]) as data
group by value
)

select data[1] from test
```

This returns null for me.

Comment: [PostgreSQL multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403844/postgresql-multidimensional-arrays)