# How to convert one nested array to a simple array in PostgresSQL?

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I am having a hard time to figure out how to convert a nested array to a simple array in postgresSQL.

I got one column with the content `[["one", "two", "three"]]` and I would like to alter the column to have `["one", "two", "three"]`. So basically to remove one nested array.

Anyone knows how to do it?

EDIT: I would need to update all the current values on the DB via an ALTER COLUMN

Comment: Is that  JSON array or a native array? The square brackets and double quotes seem to indicate it's a JSON value

Comment: It is a JSON array yes.

Comment: `select the_column -> 0 from ...`

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0efb7061d841bfbb50e359a21cb9914b)

Supposed you don't have a JSON array, you can use `unnest()` to extract all elements into one row and reaggregate these elements:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT unnest(/*your array*/)
)
```

Further Reading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25997497/3984221

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6289a8b6189d0ce4ac4b47d4ef10ca95)

If you have JSON array, you can

1. use `json_array_elements()` do extract all elements

   ```
   SELECT
       json_array_elements(a)
   FROM (
       SELECT '[["one", "two", "three"]]'::json as a
   )
   ```
2. Or you simply use the `->` operator to fetch the first element:

   ```
   SELECT
       a -> 0
   FROM (
       SELECT '[["one", "two", "three"]]'::json as a
   )s
   ```

---

Update all JSON data:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1affbbc56f1180c5dec5733f1568b82f)

```
UPDATE t
SET mydata = mydata -> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is a json array. How do I manage to apply your SQL to update all the entries already  in the DB at once?

Comment: Did this help? Please don't forget to upvote every helpful answer and additionally accept the most helpful to show that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

> I would need to update all the current values on the DB via an ALTER COLUMN

To update a column value, you use `UPDATE` not `ALTER`

The following will replace the value in the column with the "nested" array.

```
update the_table
  set the_column = the_column -> 0
where jsonb_typeof(the_column) = 'array'
  and jsonb_typeof(the_column -> 0) = 'array';
```

If the column is defined as `json` not as `jsonb` (which it should be), then you need to use `json_typeof()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each 1D array from a 2D array with `SLICE 1` and [array_to_json()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a [FOREACH statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) as shown below, then you can use them for what you want.

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR[];
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['four', 'five', 'six']
  ];
BEGIN       -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  FOREACH temp SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', array_to_json(temp);
  END LOOP;      -- ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
END
$$;
```

Then, you can get each 1D array from the 2D array as shown below:

```
INFO:  ["one","two","three"]
INFO:  ["four","five","six"]
DO
```

In addition, you can use `SLICE 2` as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR[];
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['four', 'five', 'six']
  ];
BEGIN       -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  FOREACH temp SLICE 2 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', array_to_json(temp);
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, you can get the whole 2D array as shown below:

```
INFO:  [["one","two","three"],["four","five","six"]]
DO
```

And, you can use `SLICE 0` without `array_to_json()` as shown below. *You need to change the type of `temp` local variable from `VARCHAR[]` to `VARCHAR` otherwise there is error:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  -- temp VARCHAR[];
  temp VARCHAR; -- Here
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['four', 'five', 'six']
  ];
BEGIN       -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    -- RAISE INFO '%', array_to_json(temp);
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, you can get each element from the 2D array as shown below:

```
INFO:  one
INFO:  two
INFO:  three
INFO:  four
INFO:  five
INFO:  six
DO
```