# Order by first element of two dimensional array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to reorder the multidimensional arrays of each row by the first element.

Current table:

| id | foobar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{1.2,0.01}, {5.3, 0.05}, {3.5, 0.6}} |

Desired table:

| id | foobar_reorder |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{5.3, 0.05}, {3.5, 0.6}, {1.2,0.01}} |

I am new to sql, but I am thinking that I could unnest the arrays into a table then sort by the column and turn back into an array.  I am not able to put in my actual table and column to create the output table, but it works for the code with a test array below.

Unnest array in table:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT t.aij_wij AS arr from public.pipe_aggr t
)
SELECT 
    arr[i][1] AS xi, 
    arr[i][2] AS wi
FROM 
    data, 
    generate_subscripts((SELECT arr FROM data), 1) i
```

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Unnest array with test array:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT ARRAY[[1.2,0.01],[5.3, 0.05], [3.5,0.6]]::float8[] AS arr
)
SELECT 
    arr[i][1] AS xi, 
    arr[i][2] AS wi
FROM 
    data, 
    generate_subscripts((SELECT arr FROM data), 1) i
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This orders arrays of the first dimension in descending order (while keeping a 2D array):

```sql
SELECT d.id, a.*
FROM   data d
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT array_agg(d.foobar[d1][d2]) AS arr1
      FROM   generate_subscripts(d.foobar, 1) d1
           , generate_subscripts(d.foobar, 2) d2
      GROUP  BY d1
      ORDER  BY arr1 DESC
      )
   ) a(foobar_reorder) ON d.foobar IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7HyZi4wN)

`LEFT JOIN ... ON d.foobar IS NOT NULL` keeps `null` as `null`.

See:

- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/8142998#8142998)
- [How to select 1d array from 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996237/how-to-select-1d-array-from-2d-array/25997497#25997497)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)