# Unnest first and second elements of 2D array into two 1D arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I would like to unnest this 2D array to seperate 1D array.

Current Table:

| id | ujvj |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{5.3, 0.05}, {3.5, 0.6}, {1.2,0.01}} |

Resulting table:

| id | uj | vj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {5.3, 3.5, 1.2} | {0.05, 0.6, 0.01} |

I cannot find a method of unnesting a multidimensional array by element position then putting the results back into their own 1D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exactly the given two output columns:

```sql
SELECT d.id, a.*
FROM   data d
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(d.ujvj[d1][1]) AS uj
        , array_agg(d.ujvj[d1][2]) AS vj
   FROM   generate_subscripts(d.ujvj, 1) d1
   ) a;
```

To preserve empty arrays (`'{}'`) in the source:

```sql
SELECT d.id
     , COALESCE(a.uj, d.ujvj) AS uj
     , COALESCE(a.vj, d.ujvj) AS vj
FROM   data d
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT array_agg(d.ujvj[d1][1]) AS uj
        , array_agg(d.ujvj[d1][2]) AS vj
   FROM   generate_subscripts(d.ujvj, 1) d1
   ) a ON d.ujvj <> '{}';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I_ZbcwU7)

Related:

- [Order by first element of two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77092000/order-by-first-element-of-two-dimensional-array/77092867#77092867)